# Incompatible Java Versions for WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I Installed WindowBuilder on Eclipse to create a Graphic User Interface for a program. When I go to the 'Design' tab the following error appears:

> Eclipse is running under 1.8, but this Java project has a 10 Java
>   compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes
>   from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run
>   Eclipse using a newer Java version.

I currently have Installed Java 8 (Update 171), and Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) (Eclipse Version). I had previously downloaded Java 10, but I read that there's a bug where WindowBuilder doesn't work on that version, and that it is recommened the Version 8, which is the one I downloaded and installed (after uninstalling Version 10). But the problem's still there.

What could I do to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you develop your project in Java 8? Your code should still compile in Java 10 with, at most, minor changes (unless you're depending on or doing some fancy stuff)

Comment: @ifly6 Yes of course I can, the problem here is that WindowBuider doesn't work. I don't know how to solve that problem :( I don't care about the version, the thing here is that the plugin doesn't work

Comment: "this Java project has a 10 Java compliance level" points to changing that value from the project's Properties dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change the compliance level of the project from 10 to 1.8, rebuild and the **Design** tab should work:

1. To change the project's compliance level:

   - Select the project's node in **Project Explorer**, right-click and select **Properties**.
   - Select **Java Compiler** from the column on the left.
   - Uncheck *Use Compliance from execution environment...*
   - Select 1.8 from the drop list for **Compiler compliance level**. (Presumably its current value is 10.)
   - Click the **Apply and Close** button.
2. Rebuild the project using 1.8 compliance.
3. The **Design** tab should work fine now.

[image: complianceLevel]

As a separate issue, since you have uninstalled Java 10 you should also remove it from your Installed JREs if you haven't done that already:

- **Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs**
- Select the entry for JDK 10 and click the **Remove** button.
- If the JDK 10 entry was checked when you removed it you will be forced to check another JRE definition.
- Click the **Apply and Close** button.

Comment: I did another project, added the windowbuilder application and now It works perfectly! Thank you so much. Thumbs up.

Comment: i did not have to uninstall any jre. All I did was to follow the first steps you listed for changing project compliance. thanks

Comment: @leeCoder You are right; uninstalling Java 10 is certainly not necessary to get everything working. But the OP mentioned that they had (unnecessarily) chosen to uninstall 10, so I just pointed out in my answer that it should also be removed from within Eclipse to complete the clean up process.

Answer (score 2):

WB 1.9.1 has solved the issue:

https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Comment: I disagree. I still had this issue until l follow the accepted answer  by skomisa

Answer (score -1):

Just change the compliance level of the project from the current to 1.8, rebuild and the Design tab should work:
It works for me

Comment: How does this add anything to the [answer posted by skomisa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414146/10871073) some time ago?