# Cannot install windowbuilder plugin on eclipse photon

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder, eclipse-photon

I've installed eclipse photon on my new pc (with ubuntu 18).
When i try to get it from the marketplace or from the link (http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.8/) i get this error:

No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.8/.

I tried to install the previous version, but i get the "Eclipse running under 0" error when i try to open a java file with windowbuilder. How can i solve this?

Comment: [1] I had the same problem downloading 4.8 as you, but that issue is off topic for StackOverflow. [2] The other issue (_"Eclipse running under 0"_) is because you are using Java 10. WindowBuilder has compatibility issues with that, so use Java 8 or Java 9 instead. Possible duplicate of [Eclipse Oxygen Window Builder Error with Java SE 10.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50124714/2985643). Also see [Incompatible Java Versions for WindowBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51408029/2985643).

Comment: This has been fixed in windowbuilder 1.9.1 Please upgrade
https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution here [Eclipse Windowbuilder Incompatible Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427447/eclipse-windowbuilder-incompatible-java) by modifying the .ini file in the eclipse root i managed to open window builder with jdk 1.8!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your Eclipse version: Windows builder requires a specific version of Eclipse to run. You can check on Windows Builder Website.
2. Check your Eclipse installation to make sure there are no corrupt files, you can try reinstalling.
3. Use Eclipse Marketplace: Open Eclipse and go to Help> Eclipse Marketplace, then search for Windows Builder and follow the installation prompts.